# postgres vacuum memory limits not enforced

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres v12, when maintenance_work_mem and autovacuum_work_mem are set, my understanding is that the vacuum and autovacuum sessions should be limited to use the memory limits set by these parameters. But I am seeing more memory being used than these limits by autovacuum sessions, any reason why this would happen? autovacuum_work_mem is set to 100mb but I am seeing the autovacuum process taking couple of GBs.

-- Updated after jjanes response. Yes looks like RES includes shared memory. But when default_statistics_target is increased to 3000, the session usage is 463mb, which is way more than 20mb maintenance_work_mem and 128mb shared_buffer. Shouldn't the process memory be capped to 20+128mb?

```
postgres=# show maintenance_work_mem ;
 maintenance_work_mem 
----------------------
 20MB
(1 row)
postgres=# vacuum analyze mdm_context;
VACUUM
postgres=# show shared_buffers;
 shared_buffers 
----------------
 128MB
(1 row)

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                            
 62246 postgres  20   0  422892 165996 139068 R 57.1 15.7  25:06.34 postgres: postgres postgres [local] VACUUM    


postgres=# show default_statistics_target;
 default_statistics_target 
---------------------------
 100
(1 row)
postgres=# set default_statistics_target=3000;
SET
postgres=# vacuum analyze mdm_context;
VACUUM

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                            
 62246 postgres  20   0  876132 474384   2976 R 62.9 47.6  25:11.41 postgres: postgres postgres [local] VACUUM
```

Comment: It can touch all of shared memory, plus 100mb of private memory.  Many tools will report the sum of those two sizes as the process's memory usage.

Comment: @jjanes please see the updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANALYZE is not constrained by the *_mem settings.  It does not have a mechanism for spilling to disk, or for batching, and just uses as much memory as needed to do the work implied by default_statistics_target (or the per-column settings, if those are used)